# Select from database if last_updated = NOW() OR last_updated < NOW()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to do a query to check if there are values for today, and if not, display the closest entry before today.

This is the query i use:

```
$variable = 'var1';

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `something` = '".$variable."' 
                      AND `last_updated` = NOW() OR last_updated < NOW()
```

Let's say the `table` looks like this:

```
something | last_updated
 var1     |  2013-08-04
 var1     |  2013-08-05
 var1     |  2013-08-06
```

If i delete `var1` with `last_updated` = `2013-08-06` the query returns `2013-08-04`

Why it is not returned the previous day (or the closest one) if today is `2013-08-06` using this query?

Comment: "If i delete var1 with last_updated = 2013-08-06 the query returns 2013-08-04", please indicate the exact queries involved. Your question is not clear enough as it stands

Comment: Can you show your `delete` query ?

Comment: @Yellow Bird: it's not about the delete query. i simply delete it from phpmyadmin. i am in development right now.

Comment: @dendini: i could not be more exact than that... the sample query is exactly the one i used in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
    something = variable
AND
    last_updated <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY
    last_updated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Might be able to speed up the query by adding an index to the `last_updated` column

Answer (score 4):

You've got a larger problem, having to do with operator precedence: `OR` is evaluated last, so your logic will include a row under either of these conditions:

- `something = variable AND last_updated = NOW()`, *or*
- `last_updated < NOW()`

The likelihood of a date and time equaling `NOW()` (current date and time, to the second) is pretty low, so the logic will shift to the second condition which will probably return every row in your table because it's only looking at `last_updated`.

If you want the most recently updated row for a `something` (and barring future update dates) I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE something = variable
  AND last_updated <= NOW()
ORDER BY last_updated
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Or he could put brackets around `last_updated = NOW() OR last_updated < NOW()`

Comment: True, though that basically makes it `last_updated <= NOW()`. I gotta admit that that part of the query confused me a bit. I interpreted it as wanting the closest record to "now", but I could be way off :)

Comment: Yeah sure, I just wrote this for the OP to know both possibilities :)

Answer (score 2):

The mySQL function NOW() returns both the date and the current server time. You have only indicated that you want the date so you should use the CURDATE() function.

Comment: This should result in the same behaviour btw.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add brackets on `last_updated` in where claus

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `something` = '".$variable."' 
        AND (`last_updated` = NOW() OR last_updated < NOW())
```

OR

just remove the `last_updated = NOW()` and change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `something` = '".$variable."' 
        AND last_updated <= NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you cant fetch the record of now(), you can remove the unwanted now()(current timestamp) where clause, and check your query withouth the `something` = '".$variable."' condition , as you mentioned code should returns the all records which is below now()(current timestamp).

run the below query with details you were mentioned

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  
                   last_updated < NOW()
```

you will get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$variable = 'var1';

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `something` = '".$variable."' 
                      AND `last_updated` <= NOW();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. it returns `2013-08-04` even if today is `2013-08-06` and the closest entry is from `2013-08-05`.

Comment: For Now() Sql will take timezone which was set to the server. Try with "NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY" instead of "Now()" and check what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the entry with `last_updated = 2013-08-04` is the first row which matches your condition `last_updated < now()` I'm sure the query will return the second row as well, but I guess you're just look at the first row in your result set (just guessing, because you're answers doesn't made that clear). So adding a

```
ORDER BY last_updated DESC
```

will ensure that the first row is the newest one which matches your condition, while additionally adding

```
LIMIT 1
```

will ensure that it's the ONLY one which is returned.